# Telegram bot не отправляет аудио файл

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Бот должен отправить аудио файл, но почему-то не отправляет, никакой ошибки не выдаёт.
Вот код:

```
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('мой токен')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def send_audio(user_id):
    if message.text.lower() == 'music':
        bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, 'file_unique_id')  # file_unique_id взял у бота Show Json Bot
    
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот по этому примеру попробуйте

```
audio = open(r'/manu/filename.mp3', 'rb')
bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio)
audio.close()
```